# Is this error caused by a 64-bit library being accessed by a Java program running in a 32-bit JVM?

Tags: java, c, jvm, java-native-interface, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to create a simple Java app that uses JNI to call some native functions. I've followed the examples in the JNI Programming Guide and can't seem to get them to work. I have the following Hello World program, written in Java:

```
class HelloWorld {
    private native void print();

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new HelloWorld().print();
    }

    static {
        System.load("/home/mike/Desktop/libHelloWorld.so");
    }
}
```

I compile it using `javac HelloWorld.java`, just like normal.

I also have the C implementation of the print function, in the HelloWorld.c file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return;
}
```

Then I run `javah -jni HelloWorld`, and finally the following:

```
gcc34 -shared -fpic -o libHelloWorld.so -I/<path to JDK>/include -I/<path to JDK>/include/linux HelloWorld.c
```

gcc34 is the name of the GCC program on my machine here at work (I don't control that) and I obviously place the real path to the JDK in that command. When I run my program, using the standard `java HelloWorld`, I get an error saying the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/mike/Desktop/libHelloWorld.so: /home/mike/Desktop/libHelloWorld.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible causes: architecture word width mismatch)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1778)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1674)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
    at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:8)
Could not find the main class: HelloWorld. Program will exit.
```

I know I'm running a 32-bit JVM (and unfortunately, as of right now, I'm not allowed to get a 64-bit JVM). I tried telling GCC to compile in 32-bit mode using the "-m32" option, but we don't have (and again, can't get) what we need for that. EDIT: I was able to move my files to a machine able to compile in 32-bit mode. So I did that, then verified that my libHelloWorld.so file was 32-bit by runnning `file libHelloWorld.so` and got `ELF32-bit MSB dynamic lib SPARC Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available`. I also ran `java -version` and got `Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build <blah>, mixed mode)` so it seems this JVM is running in 32-bit mode.

Why am I still getting this error?

Comment: +1 for a very well-described question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup :-).  SO won't let me submit a one-word answer, so here are some [possibly-useful Google hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=jni+%22wrong+ELF+class%22).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I already Googled it and just wanted to make sure... if we're right, it means my job's going to become a lot harder, haha. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm very curious why you're not able to somehow get access to a 32-bit compiler.  Even if you don't have the actual hardware available, could you use a virtual machine (or a cloud like EC2)?

Comment: You can submit a one-word answer if it is a long enough word.  Welsh and German are useful for this - but prohibited on SO.

Comment: Seems the problem still exists... see above!

Comment: Nevermind! When I moved the files over to the new machine that could compile in 32-bit, I forgot to change the path that System.load is given. I did that now, and it works. Thanks again Matt.